# if i don't use NetworkComms.Shutdown will i break something?

Tags: c#, networking

Hey i recently created a text message application in c# that sends messages back in forth in a console. I used  NetworkCommsDotNet & NetworkCommsDotNet.Connections.

When i was researching about it i found a command NetworkComms.Shutdown() http://www.networkcomms.net/api/html/M_NetworkCommsDotNet_NetworkComms_Shutdown.htm

I'm also new to programming so i really didn't completely understand what they where saying and was still left wondering if I don't use this in my program, will it break something or mess up my router in any way?

ps - the program works and i had success with testing it between two computers on my home network.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this, nor even know what it is, however I am good at reading documentation and believe what they tell me (for the most part)

> Shutdown all connections, threads and execute `OnCommsShutdown` event.
> Any packet handlers are left unchanged. **If any network activity has
> taken place this should be called on application close**.

The reason why it's telling you this is that it's most likely using unmanaged resources, and most likely wants to gracefully shut them down or clean them up. Since there is no open source for this project, we can only listen to what it's telling you.